# react setState not rendering everytime button is pressed

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to use setState to access my css const mystyle object to change the background color on  the squares from blue to red but everytime the button is pressed. It seems everytime I press the button the Setstate does not render on screen any advice or help? Would be greatly appreciated

```
class MyHeader extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {backgroundColor: 'blue'};
  }

  
  render() {
    const mystyle = {
    borderRadius: "10px",
    background: this.state.backgroundColor,
    padding: "10px",
    width: "100px",
    height: "100px",
    marginTop: "10px",
    lineHeight: "80px",
    color: "dimGrey",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    fontSize: "3em",
    textAlign: "center"
  };
     
  function State() {
    this.setState({backgroundColor: 'red'})
  }

    return (
      <div>
      <h1 style={mystyle}></h1>
        <h1>{this.state.backgroundColor}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


function Test() {
  
  function Test2() {
    setchange(change + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));
    if(change > 20) {
      setchange(change + Math.floor(Math.random() - 10))
    }
  }
  
  const [change, setchange] = React.useState(1)
    return (
        <div>
        <h1>click the button to randomize colors</h1>
        <button onClick={this.State}>Randomize colors!</button>
        <div className='.flex-item'></div>
        <h1>{change}</h1>
       <div className="flex-item"></div>
        
        <MyHeader />
        <MyHeader />
   
        </div>
    );
}



ReactDOM.render(<Test />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

[my codepen link to the code](https://codepen.io/jsmirga22/pen/MWoWOKe?editors=1111)

Comment: it looks like you are trying to use `this` when you are not in a class function

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is trying to do something where the child component, MyHeader, has the function to change state, but trying to invoke it from the parent component, Test.   It's just simpler to pass the color as a prop from `Test` to `MyHeader`.

Alternatively, you can do the `useContext` thing, but I think this is easier.  I've stripped out all superfluous code that wasn't getting used. You can of course, add them back as you need to.

```
const MyHeader = ({backgroundColor}) => {
  
    const mystyle = {
      borderRadius: "10px",
      background: backgroundColor,
      padding: "10px",
      width: "100px",
      height: "100px",
      marginTop: "10px",
      lineHeight: "80px",
      color: "dimGrey",
      fontWeight: "bold",
      fontSize: "3em",
      textAlign: "center"
    };
     
    return (
      <div>
      <h1 style={mystyle}></h1>
        <h1>{backgroundColor}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Test = (props) => {

  const [backgroundColor, setBackgroundColor] = useState("blue");
 
  const onButtonClick = () => {
      setBackgroundColor("red");
  }

  return (
        <div>
          <h1>click the button to randomize colors</h1>
          <button onClick={onButtonClick}>Randomize colors!</button>
          <div className='.flex-item'></div>
          <h1>{change}</h1>
          <div className="flex-item"></div>
          <MyHeader backgroundColor={backgroundColor} />
       </div>
    );

};
```